# Smoke Simulation has weird artifacts and looks low res

Tags: smoke-simulation, artifacts

[image]

I can't figure out why my smoke looks like this. It has weird artifacts and looks like it was rendered on 144 resolution. This was actually rendered in 2560 x 3840. I also used 400 samples and I'm using cycles.

Here are the domain settings
[image]

And here are the emitter settings
[image]

I've done a few simulations that have turned out perfect, but this one is just not working.

Edit: so I increased the domain resolution but the wisps look weird now. They looks low res also. Is there a way to get rid of the wisps. Maybe increasing the density or something.

[image]

Comment: increase the resolution for the domain. Read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can:

- Increase the domain's [Division value](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html#options) (this will change how the smoke simulates, interacts and looks and will increase simulation time)
- Turn on [Smoke High Resolution](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html#smoke-high-resolution) (this will introduce noise into the simulation to add detail, more [info in manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html#note-on-divisions-and-high-resolution)).
- Check if the domain material has Cubic set for it's voxel interpolation (should be by default):

  [image]

Volumetric domains are like raster images but in 3D. Imagine rendering a low resolution texture close to camera on a FullHD render - no matter what you do, even if you go to 4K, the texture would still render as ugly blob.

Comment: I increased the domain resolution but the wisps look weird. I edited the post and added a picture.

Comment: @AlexPensotti If you don't want the wisps, you need to simulate with lower divisions and rather turn on *High Resolution*, that should give you the look you are after.

Answer (score 0):

just quickly flying through. I found this and it might help. It's under Render Properties in Volumes. Step Size set to lower than original 0.1 m solved my issue with the same looking cubic smoke. Try it and let me know if it had worked for you too. Cheers!
[image]